# How can I close my executeable Java Application properly?

Tags: java, swing, deployment, jar, awt

I deployed my Java application as an executeable Java App, and it works nice and well when I am closing it and want to rename it, it can not be done because OpenJDK is running.

How can I close OpenJDK when I am exiting the Application?
Ps: That is the "Application is used" prompt but in this case on german
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izmkB.png)

Comment: `System.exit(0);`?

Comment: No problem, I've now added an answer.  Could you please mark it as "accepted" to make it easier to find for future visitors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, you can always terminate the program by calling the [`System.exit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#exit(int)) method.  It takes one argument, which is the exit code.  Typically, programs return an exit code of `0` to indicate that everything went well, or if an error was thrown, they return the error code as the exit code.  Therefore, the commonly accepted way to terminate a program gracefully is:

```java
System.exit(0);
```